# Curved lines pattern

Tags: vector, adobe, adobe-illustrator

I am a real Illustrator newbie, so I hope someone can help me!

I am tying to achieve a curved pattern, kind of like the image below.

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ugpnF.jpg)

I really don't know how to do it! I prefer the result to be a vector illustration. Is there in Illustrator some kind of smudge tool like the one in Ps? Or any other ideas to achieve the same result? I have tried Effect>Wrap but i never seem to be able to have the result I want.

Thank you so much in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can try Envelope Distort tool (Illustrator Menu: Object->Envelope Distort -> Make with Mesh). In Envelope Mesh Dialog set rows:4, columns:4 (or other values). Then using Direct Selection Tool (A) select some of mesh nodes and move in various directions.

Comment: That is exactly what I needed! Thank you so much! :-)